# Do Cloudformation policies stack (are they transitive)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm working on a lambda function `A` that accesses another lambda function `B` that accesses a database `C`, and want to know if the IAM policies are transitive.

```
A <-> B <-> C
```

`B` has access to `C` using a policy in cloudformation (example below in appendix)

`A` has access to `B` using this policy (also below, excuse the mix of JSON and YAML)

**My question is:**

Does the fact that `B` can access `C` mean that if `A` calls `B` then `B` will be able to access `C`, or does `A` also need explicit access to `C`?

---

### Appendix

Policy that gives `B` access to `C`:

```
- PolicyName: RDSAccess
  PolicyDocument:
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
      - "rds-data:ExecuteStatement"
      Resource:
      - !Ref DBClusterARN
```

Policy that gives `A` access to `B`.

```
"managementaccesspolicy": {
      "DependsOn": [
        "LambdaExecutionRole"
      ],
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyName": "management-access-policy",
        "Roles": [
          {
            "Ref": "LambdaExecutionRole"
          }
        ],
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
              "Resource": {
                "Fn::Sub": [
                  "arn:aws:lambda:${region}:${account}:function:*",
                  {
                    "region": {
                      "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                    },
                    "account": {
                      "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: How the DB is accessed? Using IAM authentication?

Comment: I have simplified it a little, but it's accessed using a secret we could call `D` that has its own policy. If you think it would help I can add it to the question body, but I left it off to make the question simpler.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the fact that B can access C mean that if A calls B then B will be able to access C, or does A also need explicit access to C?

Its **not transitive**. If the only function that can access the secret to DB is C, then only C can access the DB.

In this case, A has to call C to access DB.